# relate multiple fileupload with checkboxes in PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, checkbox

I want to do something when a file is uploaded and the related checkbox is checked in PHP,
how do i link the file input type with the checkbox?

this is what i have:

```
<input type="file" name="file_upload[]"  /> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]"> linked to file-upload 1 <br/>
<input type="file" name="file_upload[]"  /> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]"> linked to file-upload 2 <br/>
<input type="file" name="file_upload[]"  /> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]"> linked to file-upload 3 <br/>
<input type="file" name="file_upload[]"  /> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]"> linked to file-upload 4 <br/>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give them unique names:

```
<input type="file" name="file_upload[0]">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[0]">

<input type="file" name="file_upload[1]">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[1]">
```

PHP will still represent them as arrays.

Answer (score -1):

You may try to set some variable which shows successful upload and then check your checkbox by java script